# Não estou conseguindo realizar o seguinte exercicio em python

Tags: python

Não estou conseguindo realizar o seguinte exercício em python:

> João Papo-de-Pescador, homem de bem, comprou um microcomputador para controlar o rendimento diário de seu trabalho. Toda vez que ele traz um peso de peixes maior que o estabelecido pelo regulamento de pesca do estado de São Paulo (50 quilos) deve pagar uma multa de R$ 4,00 por quilo excedente. João precisa que você faça um programa que leia a variável peso (peso de peixes) e calcule o excesso. Gravar na variável excesso a quantidade de quilos além do limite e na variável multa o valor da multa que João deverá pagar. Imprima os dados do programa com as mensagens adequadas.

Eis aqui o que tentei:

```
pesos = input('Digite o numero de quilos q vc pegou:')

if pesos > 50:
    pesos -= 50
    excesso = pesos
    multa = excesso * 4

    print 'Total da multa: ' + str(multa)
else:
    print 'Não teve excesso'
```

Comment: 1. Leia o peso. 2. Se o valor for maior que 50 quilos, subtraia 50 para achar o excesso e armazene isso na variável "excesso", ou em caso contrário, atribua zero a essa variável. 3. Multiplique o "excesso" por 4 e guarde isso na variável "multa".

Comment: Ae valeu bro vou fazer isso

Comment: Victor tem como corrigir meu programa? acho q fiz algo errado

Comment: Posta ele aqui. Edite a pergunta.

Comment: ok coloquei ali está

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dá para simplificar um pouquinho o seu código e não esquecer de mostrar o excesso também, além da multa:

```
pesos = int(input('Digite o número de quilos que você pegou:'))

if pesos > 50:
    excesso = pesos - 50
    multa = excesso * 4

    print 'Total do excesso: ' + str(excesso)
    print 'Total da multa: ' + str(multa)
else:
    print 'Não teve excesso'
```

Comment: Mais o q eu fiz estava certo?

Comment: @Twz3xc21SadHack Essencialmente sim.

Comment: ok muito obd pq eu tava achando q parte da multa tava errada, mas n estava certa agr vou continuar com os exercicios vlw ai

Comment: Talvez é bom salientar que esse código funcionará apenas no Python 2. No Python 3 o retorno de `input` é sempre uma *string*, o que geraria erro ao compará-lo com um inteiro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Corrigido.

Answer (score -1):

o codigo pode ficar assim, mais resumido e usando o .format em vez de somar as strings

```
pesos = input('Digite o numero de quilos q vc pegou:')
if pesos > 50:
    multa = (pesos - 50) * 4
    print ('Total da multa: {}'.format(multa))
else:
    print ('Não teve excesso')
```

Answer (score -3):

print("Peso permitido pelo estado: 40 Kg")

print("Multa por Kg Excedente: R$ 4,00")

peso =float(input("Digite Quantos Kg de Peixe você trouxe: "))

excesso = peso - 50

multa = excesso * 4

if excesso <= 0:
print("Parabéns, você não excedeu o peso e nao pagará multa. Seu peso foi: ", peso)

else:
print("Ops, Você excedeu: ", excesso, " Kg")

```
print("Por esse motivo deve pagar uma multa no valor de R$: ", multa)
```